# Can a Pen or Brush paint a Point?

Tags: c#, winforms, point, brush, pen

I know that I can draw a filled circle and I can draw many simple and complicated things with a Graphics. But I couldn't get it to draw a single point (not a single pixel).

I'm playing with a Paint program and the user can draw fine but not plot a dot. I can add a dummy point really close or can draw a filled cirlce but sometimes I miss the obvious.

So is there a way to **draw a single point with a given Brush or Pen**?

And no, of course I don't mean to draw a single Pixel. I want to use the Properties like color and width. Like a DrawLine with only one Point or with the same Point twice. But that renders nothing.

Comment: Can you post a sreenshot of what you mean?

Comment: That should not be necessary. Imagine a thick line, now make it shorter and shorter. Shorter, not thinner. When it is reduced to a single Point it will look like..well, it should look like an endpoint, not even necessarily a cirlce.

Comment: What's the difference between a single point and a single pixel in your world?

Comment: A point is a geometrical construct, like a line or a circle. When you draw it you use a tool like a pen or a brush of a certain width and color and you add color to your drawing surface. Here the surface consists of pixels. If the width of my pen is 1 then the point would indeed be just one pixel wide but, as I have written in my OP, I want to use a given Pen with its given width.

Comment: You can't get around the fact that WinForms is pixel based.  Make sure you have the smoothmode antialiased.  Do provide some code or a picture that demonstrates what problem you are having.

Comment: A single pixel is a 1x1 rectangle.  Use Graphics.FillRectangle()

Comment: Sigh. I must have a really bad day expressing myself. I was missing a Graphics.DrawPoint(Pen, Point) method. But hey, I can write one myself, thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public void DrawPoint(Graphics G, Pen pen, Point point)
    {
        // add more LineCaps as needed..
        int pw2 = (int ) Math.Max(1, pen.Width / 2);
        using(var brush = new SolidBrush(pen.Color))
        {
            if (pen.EndCap == LineCap.Square)
                G.FillRectangle(brush, point.X - pw2, point.Y - pw2, pen.Width, pen.Width);
            else
                G.FillEllipse(brush, point.X - pw2, point.Y - pw2, pen.Width, pen.Width);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would encase the code into a `using(var brush = new SolidBrush(){ ... }` statement to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I edited the code, to show what I meant. You *almost* had it!