# Draw a single point

Tags: c#, wpf

Must be a simple question, yet I can't find or figure out myself solution to it.

How to draw a **single** point in wpf?

In winforms I did something like

```
graphics.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x+1, y+1);
```

But in wpf `x` and `y` become `double` (or well, actually I never used `float` in winforms), then there is a `Pen` and device dependend/independent units, so adding +1 doesn't looks good anymore. How would you draw single point in wpf?

Comment: The 'solution' for WinForms doesn't really look good, it is more of an oval. The way to do it, since a DrawPoint is lacking is to draw a filled circle with the width of the pen. See my own [question here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763643/can-a-pen-or-brush-paint-a-point)

Comment: @Taw, `DrawEllipse(brush, null, x, y, d / 2, d / 2)` (d - diameter or `Pen` thickness) produces good results, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can draw a point in a number of ways in WPF. One way is using the [`Ellipse` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse(v=vs.110).aspx)... try this XAML:

```
<Ellipse Width="1" Height="1" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Alternatively, you could try using the [`DrawingContext.DrawEllipse` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawellipse(v=vs.110).aspx) to draw your point:

```
YourDrawingContext.DrawEllipse(YourBrush, YourPen, YourPointPosition, radiusX, radius);
```

Comment: Using DrawEllipse for drawing a point from a pen (color and thickness) you should have Brush=null and radius=0. Alternatively Brush=pen.Brush and Radius=pen.Thickness/2. Both works in my application, but I haven't tested alpha blending for which I think the former may have issues, depending on how the internals are implemented.